# How to refresh PageViewController in ios (StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6

I have used `PageViewController` in my application for showing images & delete option is there if any user want to delete particular image from `pageViewController` then user can delete it, but the problem i am facing that when user delete an image from `PageViewController` then after deleting it ,deleted image shows back of the `PageViewController` when scroll the images,Anybody can help me to resolve this issue, that how to refresh PageController.

Comment: When you delete the image, it also deleted from the array containing image?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to force UIPageViewController to forget about cached view controllers of neighbouring pages that are currently not displayed:

```
pageViewController.dataSource = nil;
pageViewController.dataSource = self;
```

I do this every time I change the set of pages. Of course this doesn't affect the currently displayed page.

With this workaround I avoid the caching bug and can still use     animated:YES in setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:.

Comment: still its showing deleted image on the back of the pageViewController scrollView.

Comment: When you delete the image, it also deleted from the array containing image?

Comment: Actually , i want that when user see images in PageViewController like Photo album if there four image then user when user will see those image then he should be able to delete particular image , after deleteing an image   pageView Controller should show three images, This all work has done but the problem is that whenever i delete an image the it goes an set back of the PageViewController scroll View, so now when i scroll PageController then it show image on backside,

Comment: Same problem is working fine, if i come back to previous controller after deleting an image.Then its working fine but if i delete an image on sameView then start to scroll images, then issue comes.

Comment: what is the type of array?